# Definition of equivalence of polynomial under a F[x] where is F is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]

I am confused about this definition specially the highlighted part, can some one explain it? example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here equivalence means $f$ and $g$ have exactly the same roots with same multiplicities.

Suppose we take the polynomial $f(x)=2x^2-2$, then it is equivalent to $g(x)=x^2-1$ as $f(x)=2.g(x)$.

Suppose you take the polynomial $f(x)=2x^2+3x+5$, then $f(x)=2.(x^2+\frac32x+\frac52)$. Hence $f(x)$ is equivalent to the monic polynomial $x^2+\frac32x+\frac52$.

In fact divide any polynomial by its leading coefficient and you get a monic polynomial which is equivalent to the original polynomial.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it makes a lot more sense. :)